# Harmonic function on an open set is infinite dimensional

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-functions, laplacian

I want to prove that the space of harmonic function on an open set $\Omega\subset R^N$ $(N\geq 2)$ is uncountablely infinite dimensional.

That is, I want to prove that

$$A:=\{u\in C^0(\Omega),\,\,u\text{ is harmonic }\}$$
has uncountablely infinite dimensions...

I actually have no idea how to get start. From what I learned in Functional analysis, we usually prove some Banach space is uncountablely infinite dimensional by using Zorn's lemma. But here I can not give a norm on $A$ since $u$ could be unbounded...

Comment: What kind of dimension are you talking about?

Comment: I am viewing space $A$ as a vector space so I think the logical choice should be the number of minimal vectors which can span the space $A$.

Comment: For infinite-dimensional spaces like this it is much more useful to work with Schauder bases, where you allow infinite linear combinations, i.e., limits of finite linear combinations. Then you will usually get away with a more or less explicit countably infinite basis, without having to use the Axiom of Choice or Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: I don't really get it... could you please write a bit more details?

Comment: There are two kinds of basis commonly discussed for infinite dimensional spaces: Hamel (algebraic) bases, which are exactly the kind of bases you learn about for finite-dimensional spaces, and Schauder bases, which have a notion of infinite summation. (For example, the Fourier basis $\{e^{ni\theta}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a Schauder basis for $L^2(I)$, $I$ some interval.) A notion of "dimension" can be defined for both kinds of basis, and the two notions are inequivalent, so you ought to specify what sort of basis you refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plane, harmonic functions are exactly the real parts of (complex) analytic functions, which can be represented by power series with an infinite radius of convergence. E.g., you can linearly embed the space $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{C})$ of bounded sequences of complex numbers into the space of harmonic functions in the plane by $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \mapsto \mathrm{Re} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}{a_n} z^n\right)$.

The space $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{C})$ does not have a countable basis which is probably easiest to see by showing that the set of sequences $(a^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ for $0<|a|<1$ is linearly independent.

If $N \ge 2$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ non-empty and open, then you can associate to every harmonic function $u(x,y)$ in the plane the harmonic function $u_\Omega(x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_N) := u(x_1, x_2)$. Since a harmonic function in the plane is uniquely determined by its values on any non-empty open set, this shows the claim in full generality.